# Celery: How do I chain a long running task without timing out the parent task?

Tags: python, celery

I have a task that is taking 300+ seconds to complete, and I believe (though haven't confirmed) that Celery doesn't want you to create long running tasks. So rather than increasing our Celery task time limit, I'm trying to refactor the task using [chain](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains) to break it up into more shorter running steps:

**Current code**

```
@task
def long_task():
  # Each step can take over 2 minutes
  x = step1()
  y = step2(x)
  z = step3(y)

def main():
  # this fails with timeout frequently
  long_task.delay()
```

**Refactored code**

```
@task
def step1():
  ...

@task
def step2():
  ...

@task
def step3():
  ...

@task
def chained_task():
  c = chain(step1.s(), step2.s(), step3.s())
  c.delay()

def main_refactored():
  # will this still timeout?
  chained_task.delay()
```

My question is: Will this design actually prevent the timeout? I don't think so, since the chain inside `chained_task()` still has to complete within the time limit, and just because we are taskifying the subparts and chaining them, the whole chain still has to complete serially which seems no different than before.

I want to truly break up the parent task into pieces, execute the pieces in serial order like a chain, and do that with 3 tasks taking 100s rather than a single task taking 300s. I believe `chain` is what I need, but not sure how to use it here. Thanks for your guidance!